# Difference between Azure Owner role and Co-Administrator

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-security

Our subscription has 5 resource groups.  Based on Microsoft documentation, the older "co-administrator" role is equivalent to the newer RBAC role of "Owner" when set at the subscription level.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/rbac-and-directory-admin-roles

> The Service Administrator and the Co-Administrators have the
>   equivalent access of users who have been assigned the Owner role (an
>   Azure RBAC role) at the subscription scope.

I'm not seeing this behavior.  When my account role is set to owner at the subscription level, I cannot see any resource groups.  When I set that same account to co-administrator, I can see all 5 resource groups.

How can I use the newer RBAC roles to allow owners to see all resource groups within a subscription?

Comment: UPDATE: If I give the account that is an owner of the subscription the "Global Administrator" directory role, it can see all resource groups, but I don't know why that is needed if the subscription Owner should have all rights within that subscription.

Comment: Plz check if you have any specific role assignments on these resource groups that remove inherited ones..

Comment: We do not have any overrides.  Without the Global Admin role, it can only see resource groups that it creates itself.

Comment: Can you share a (redacted, where necessary) screenshot of the subscription's Access control (IAM) view, and a screenshot of the resource group's? And verify that the resource groups are, indeed, in the subscription in question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD PowerShell to create a user them grant the "Owner" role to the user. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/tutorial-role-assignments-user-powershell).

```
#create user
Connect-AzureAD
$PasswordProfile = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.PasswordProfile
$PasswordProfile.Password = "Wdsr199545!"
New-AzureADUser -DisplayName "test User" -PasswordProfile $PasswordProfile -UserPrincipalName "test@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com" -AccountEnabled $true -MailNickName "testuser"

#grant access 
Login-AzureRmAccount
$sub = Get-AzureRmSubscription
$scope = "/subscriptions/" + $sub.Id
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName test@hanxia.onmicrosoft.com -Scope $scope -RoleDefinitionName Owner
```